# How to get a class from which tests were run while byte buddy intercept the tests from super class?

Tags: java, testing, byte-buddy

I have a service class with a method which i'll intercept in runtime:

```
package service;

public class ServiceImpl {
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And test classes, using TestNG:

```
package tests.first;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import service.ServiceImpl;

public class A {
    @Test
    public void testA() {
        ServiceImpl service = new ServiceImpl();
        // ...
        service.run();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Another class that extends the `A` class in different package:

```
package tests.second;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import service.ServiceImpl;

public class B extends A {
    @Test
    public void testB() {
        ServiceImpl service = new ServiceImpl();
        // ...
        service.run();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Also I have a proxy agent that used as an interceptor for `ServiceImpl.run` method (using byte buddy library).

*that what i tried in the inteceptor:*

```
    public void intercept() {
        Arrays.asList(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace())
            .stream()
            .map(e -> e.getClassName() + "." + e.getMethodName())
        // some actions
    }
```

**Question**:
I'm running tests in class B and while the tests are running, the interceptor should get the class name and method name from the stack trace (or something else). But tests start with class `A` and return `className: tests.first; methodName: testA`, is it possible to get in that time className for class `B` which the tests were run?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are asking a question about Byte Buddy (BB) without showing any BB code. To see the full picture and reproduce your problem, it would actually be good to see the interceptor, too. Besides, your fragmentary code snippets have no imports, so I also cannot see if you use JUnit 4, 5 or maybe another test framework like TestNG. Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and how it helps you to ask better questions and get better answers. BTW, do your tests run on Java 9+ or Java 8-? The stack trace part of my answer would depend on that information.

Comment: There is also an inconsistency in your description: In `className: tests.first; methodName: testA`, your "class name" rather seems to be the package name. So either what you wrote is wrong or you have a bug in your code. Did you mean to write `className: tests.first.A`? Please also explain what your interceptor's purpose is and why you need that information there. Parsing stack traces is a last resort, maybe it makes more sense to query the testing framework or getting the class name of the current test instance. The stack trace of displays the correct information, `A.testA()` gets executed.

Comment: @kriegaex Hi, I've exteded my question with more data about this case. I can't show BB code due to a privacy in my company. Thanks for response.

Comment: Denis, with all due respect, that is a statement unworthy of any developer. If you would have read the MCVE article I linked to, you would know that nobody needs your original code, but a stripped-down, minimal version reproducing the problem. Feel free to rename classes, packages, methods, fields, variables. Just make it illustrative. Your edit is a great first step already, just the main thing you are asking about is still missing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you Instrument both classes A and B. In this case you will see the respective stack trace of these classes when they are executed as test. Byte Buddy does not interfer with stack traces or test mechanics.

Comment: Thanks for response, looks like TestNG generates a new thread for every executable class, and i can't get data about class ```B``` from ```A``` class.